# AntiCorruption layer's Facades, Services and SRP

Tags: domain-driven-design

1)

a) *ACL Facade* offers access only to those features of the *other system* ( *external system* or perhaps even another *Bounded Context* also developed by our team ) that our *BC* needs. If *other system* exposes functionality ( which our *BC* is interested in ) that we could categorize into several different *responsibilities*, should we define one *ACL Facade* for each of these *responsibilities* or should we have single *ACL Facade* expose all the *responsibilities* ( offered by *external system* ) that our *BC* needs?

b) If answer to **a)** is that we should define *one ACL Facade for each of the responsibilities offered by external system*,  should we in turn also define *one ACL Service for each ACL Facade*?!

2)

a) Evan's book ( pg. 366 ):

> The public interface of the AntiCorruption Layer ussually appears as a
>   set of Services ... It may not even make sense , in our model, to
>   represent the external system as a single component. It may be best to
>   use multiple Services, each of which has a coherent responsibility in
>   terms of our model

*ACL* itself doesn't reside within *Domain layer*, but don't according to the above quote *ACL services* represent *domain concepts*? If so, couldn't we argue that:

I - *ACL services* are *Domain Services*?

II - that *domain concepts* have leaked into *ACL*?

b) What is the *responsibility* of *ACL service*? Simply to mediate between our *BC* and an *external system* ( ie other *BC* ) or can *ACL Service* have a *responsibility* different from the *responsibility* offered by *external system*, and as such *ACL Service* could use functionality offered by *external system* only to execute its own *designated tasks*?

3) Evan's book ( pg. 366 ):

> The public interface of the AntiCorruption Layer ussually appears as a
>   set of Services ... It may not even make sense , in our model, to
>   represent the external system as a single component. It may be best to
>   use multiple Services, each of which has a coherent responsibility in
>   terms of our model

Is author saying that it may not make sense to represent an *external system* as having a *single responsibility*, but instead that *system* could be represented as having *several responsibilities* and as such we would define *ACL Facade + ACL service* ( and corresponding *Adapter* ) for each of these *responsibilities*?

4) Btw - I assume ACL can also be defined between two *Bounded Contexts* existing within the same application and developed by the same team?

**UPDATE:**

1)

a) I don't quite understand your reasoning:

> If the facade is used by the same project at the distinct
>   responsibilities still fall into the same bounded context, then use
>   the same facade. The benefits of the technical cohesion along the
>   external system API axis will outweigh the benefits of functional
>   coupling along the responsibility axis.

I. I assume "*at*" is a typo and should be replaced with "*and*"?

II. By "*distinct responsibilities still fall into the same bounded context*" are you referring to the fact that *Facade* is only exposing *responsibilities* of a *single BC*?

III. And if *Facade* was exposing *responsibilities* of *several BCs*, then we should have *one Facade* **for each** of these *external BCs*? If yes, why is it preferred over having a single Facade for all *BCs*? Simply because the *Facade interface* would become a mess?

IV. By "*If the facade is used by the same project*" you mean if *both BCs* are part of the *same application*, then we should use *single Facade* to expose all *Responsibilities*? And what if the other *BC* belongs to a *different application*?

V.

> The benefits of the technical cohesion along the external system API
>   axis will outweigh the benefits of functional coupling along the
>   responsibility axis.

Why is *techical cohesion* preferred over *functional coupling*?

b)

> The facade itself is effectively a service or set of services. No need
>   to define an additional service.

Uhm, I'm not sure I understood this. Anyways, how do *ACL services* map to *Facade*? Perhaps *each ACL service* is mapped to *one Responsibility* that our *Facade* exposes ( ie if *Facade* exposes a *single responsibility*, then we only have *one ACL service*,if it exposes *two responsibilities*, we have *two ACL services* etc )?

3)

> > Is author saying that it may not make sense to represent an external
> >     system as having a single responsibility, but instead that system
> >     could be represented as having several responsibilities and as such we
> >     would defineACL Facade + ACL service ( and corresponding Adapter ) for
> >     each of these responsibilities?
>
> Yes, the external system may play different roles in your system. As
>   such, it can be represented as multiple services in the ACL. There is
>   no need to define an additional service for each ACL service - they
>   already are services.

I must admit I haven't yet listened to *Udi's Making Roles explicit*, so I'm kind of lost here, but I wasn't implying that we should add additional *ACL service* for each *ACL service* that we already have. Instead I was asking whether author meant we should have *one ACL service for each responsibility* ( ie if the other *BC/Facade* has *one responsibility*, we should define a *single ACL service*, if it has *two responsibilities*, we should define *two ACL Services* etc  )

4)

> Correct. However, the relationships between two BCs developed locally
>   may be different than that of the external system.

Different how?

**SECOND UPDATE:**

1)

a)

II.

> A facade encapsulates an API of an external system. If the
>   functionality provided by the API is only used by a single BC but
>   there are multiple use cases, then it is OK to have a single facade
>   service for that BC. The alternative is to create a facade for each
>   use case. This is also fine, but like I said, the technical cohesion
>   of the first approach may be beneficial.

Q1 - You're using the term "*use case*" instead of *Responsibility*. Am I correct in assuming that saying "*a Facade exposes a single Use-case*" generally suggests that *Facade exposes a single method*, while saying "*a Facade exposes a single Responsibility*" could also mean that *Facade exposes several methods* ( which together accomplish a particular task )?

Q2 - So should a *Facade* expose *Responsibilities* or *use-cases*?

V.

> Normally, functional cohesion is preferred over technical or logical
>   cohesion. Generally however, you will have mixes of both. Technical
>   cohesion can be convenient at smaller scales. For example, you may use
>   similar serialiation or translation mechanisms in a facade. It is
>   convenient to share those among facades, however not at the cost of
>   functional cohesion. Therefore, it is OK to share such functionality
>   within a single BC, but not across BCs.

From a distance a *single Facade* having *Technical cohesion* rather than *Functional cohesion* makes sense. But it gets rather confusing how this process looks in practice. To explain, assuming *external system* exposes several *responsibilities*, then we can design *Facade* such that it has *Technical cohesion* rather that *Functional cohesion* simply by having a *single Facade* exposing all the *responsibilities* offered by an *external system*.

But I'm having more difficulty imagining a scenario when *external system* ( and thus *Facade* ) exposes only a *single responsibility* – is even in such a scenario possible to  design a *Facade* in such way that it has a *Technical cohesion* rather than *Functional cohesion*? If yes, could you provide a simple example?

VI. Is *Functional cohesion* in any way related to *Side-Effect Free functions* / *Pure functions*?

2)

b)

> > Anyways, how do ACL services map to Facade? Perhaps each ACL service
> >     is mapped to one Responsibility that our Facade exposes ( ie if Facade
> >     exposes a single responsibility, then we only have one ACL service,if
> >     it exposes two responsibilities, we have two ACL services etc )?
>
> The ACL is a facade consisting of services. And yes, your assumption
>   is an acceptable way to go about it. The term facade here isn't meant
>   to refer to a single class, but the set of classes (services)
>   comprising the anti-corruption layer. It may only be one class, or it
>   may be many.

I. I think I understand what you're implying, but just to be sure - assuming *our BC* is communicating only with *one external system* and as such we only have *one Facade*, is  a *Facade* usually implemented as a *single class*?

II. Btw, I assume that *ACL services* don't call *this Facade* directly, but instead call on *methods* of corresponding *Adapters*, which in turn call *methods* on *this Facade*?

III.

> And yes, your assumption is an acceptable way to go about it.

So you're essentially suggesting that if *external system* exposes *two responsibilities*,  we should have a *single Facade* exposing *both responsibilities*, but on the other hand we should have *two ACL services*, one for each *Responsibility*?

**THIRD UPDATE:**

Your answers got me very much confused, so before I can produce any meaningful questions in response to your answers ( in both this and the other topic I made ), I must ask you the following:

As far as I understand your answers, it seems you're essentially saying that *ACL services* make up the *Facade*, meaning that *these ACL Services* represent the *interface of the Facade*? Which would also imply that *Facade belongs to our BC* since it is expressed in terms of *our BC's domain model* ( reason being that *ACL Services* are expressed in terms of *our BC's domain model* )?!

But Evans claims that *Facade* belongs in the *BC of the other system* ( and as such should be expressed using *domain concepts of external system* ), while *ACL services* should belong to *our BC* and as such should be expressed using the *domain concepts of our BC*:

pg. 367:

> The Facade belongs in the BC of the other system

So did I misunderstand your post or is your opinion on the subject a bit different than that of Evans's opinion?

thank you

Answer (score 2):

1a) If the facade is used by the same project and the distinct responsibilities still fall into the same bounded context, then use the same facade. The benefits of the technical cohesion along the external system API axis will outweigh the benefits of functional coupling along the responsibility axis.

1b) The facade itself is effectively a service or set of services. No need to define an additional service.

2a1) Yes.

2a2) Yes, however I wouldn't say leaking in a derogatory sense. The purpose of an ACL is to adapt an external model to the local domain model. Therefore, naturally, domain concepts will be there.

2b) The ACL service should only mediate between external system and your BC. The nature of this mediation can be stretched however. The central goal is protecting against corruption that can result from changes in the external model.

3) Yes, the external system may play different roles in your system. As such, it can be represented as multiple services in the ACL. There is no need to define an additional service for each ACL service - they already are services.

4) Correct. However, the relationships between two BCs developed locally may be different than that of the external system.

**UPDATE**

1a1) Yes, typo. Corrected.

1a2) A facade encapsulates an API of an external system. If the functionality provided by the API is only used by a single BC but there are multiple use cases, then it is OK to have a single facade service for that BC. The alternative is to create a facade for each use case. This is also fine, but like I said, the technical cohesion of the first approach may be beneficial.

1a3) In this case, there would be a facade in each BC. The alternative would be to try and share a facade. As you said, this would become a dependency mess.

1a4) Yes. If other BC is part of different app, create new facade specific to that BC as stated in 1a3.

1a5) Normally, functional [cohesion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_%28computer_science%29) is preferred over technical or logical cohesion. Generally however, you will have mixes of both. Technical cohesion can be convenient at smaller scales. For example, you may use similar serialiation or translation mechanisms in a facade. It is convenient to share those among facades, however not at the cost of functional cohesion. Therefore, it is OK to share such functionality within a single BC, but not across BCs.

2b) The ACL is a facade consisting of services. And yes, your assumption is an acceptable way to go about it. The term facade here isn't meant to refer to a single class, but the set of classes (services) comprising the anti-corruption layer. It may only be one class, or it may be many.

3) Yes that is what the author is saying.

4) This is also discussed in later sections of the book. The difference for local BCs could be that teams developing them can communicate and this adjust their models to fulfill requirements of the other. For external BCs, this may not be possible.

**UPDATE 2**

1a1) The term "use-case" was intended to be interchangeable with "responsibility". They could mean a single method or a few.

1a2) I think responsibilities is a better term.

V.) An external system could certainly provide only a single functions. For example, you can have a 3rd party service which returns the exchange rate for a currency. It only has a single method and the ACL would be in place in order to manage the differences in the way currencies and exchange rates are represented in the different systems. In this case however, you aren't thinking about cohesion because you only have a single responsibility.

VI.) No. It is just a type of [cohesion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_%28computer_science%29) that aligns along the domain at hand, as opposed to some technical aspect.

2b1) You'd have a single class that implements the domain service which exposes the external BC to the local BC. However, this class could make use of other classes, such as for serialization or whatever. Those classes however are "hidden" behind this service class.

2b2) The ACL services are what make up the facade. This may just be a confusion in terminology. An ACL is a facade.

2b3) You could have a single service expose both responsibilities. This way you can share some code easily - technical cohesion. However, you can also extract the shared code into a utility class that can be used by two distinct services. All I'm saying is that the first approach isn't terrible since you're still confined to a single BC.